# Locale makes my static assets in public directory not to be loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a static 404.html, 422.html, 500.html file in public directory which call stylesheets/sample.css that locates in public/stylesheets/sample.css.

When I got into www.mysite.com/404.html, it was shown up perfectly.

But, when I get into www.mysite.com/en/404.html (with locale specific) or www.mysite.com/en/hfghfg(rnndom path), my 404 page could not load it's stylesheet because it calls a stylesheet from a incorrect path ( /en/stylesheets/sample.css ).